# pandas dataframe to key value pair

Tags: pandas

What is the best way to convert following pandas dataframe to a key value pair

Before :

```
datetime             name    qty     price
2017-11-01 10:20     apple    5       1
2017-11-01 11:20     pear     2       1.5
2017-11-01 13:20     banana   10      5
```

After :

```
2017-11-01 10:20 name=apple qty=5 price=1
2017-11-01 11:20 name=pear  qty=2 price=1.5
2017-11-01 13:20 name=banana qty=10 price=5
```

note that i don't want the datetime key in my output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you need [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.drop('datetime', axis=1).to_dict(orient='records')
print (d)
[{'qty': 5, 'price': 1.0, 'name': 'apple'}, 
 {'qty': 2, 'price': 1.5, 'name': 'pear'}, 
 {'qty': 10, 'price': 5.0, 'name': 'banana'}]
```

but if need not key `datetime`:

```
d = df.set_index('datetime').to_dict(orient='index')
print (d)
{'2017-11-01 13:20': {'qty': 10, 'price': 5.0, 'name': 'banana'}, 
 '2017-11-01 10:20': {'qty': 5, 'price': 1.0, 'name': 'apple'}, 
 '2017-11-01 11:20': {'qty': 2, 'price': 1.5, 'name': 'pear'}}
```

If order is important:

```
tuples = [tup for tup in df.set_index('datetime').itertuples()]
print (tuples)

[Pandas(Index='2017-11-01 10:20', name='apple', qty=5, price=1.0), 
 Pandas(Index='2017-11-01 11:20', name='pear', qty=2, price=1.5), 
 Pandas(Index='2017-11-01 13:20', name='banana', qty=10, price=5.0)]
```

EDIT:

New `DataFrame` was created with column names and old values was added. Last write [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = df.set_index('datetime').astype(str)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(np.array(df.columns), len(df.index)).reshape(len(df.index), -1), 
                   index=df.index, 
                   columns=df.columns) + '='
df1 = df1.add(df)
print (df1)
                         name     qty      price
datetime                                        
2017-11-01 10:20   name=apple   qty=5  price=1.0
2017-11-01 11:20    name=pear   qty=2  price=1.5
2017-11-01 13:20  name=banana  qty=10  price=5.0

df1.to_csv('filename.csv', header=None)

2017-11-01 10:20,name=apple,qty=5,price=1.0
2017-11-01 11:20,name=pear,qty=2,price=1.5
2017-11-01 13:20,name=banana,qty=10,price=5.0
```

Comment: 2017-11-01 10:20 name='apple', qty='5', price='1.0'     .. I don't mind the data in this format dumped into a file.

Comment: Ok, give me a sec

Answer (score 9):

If you are happy with a dictionary as output, you can use

```
df.to_dict('index')
```

On your example (with a slight parsing error for the dates by `read_clipboard`) this results in:

```
In [17]: df = pd.read_clipboard().reset_index(drop=True)

In [18]: df.to_dict('index')
Out[18]: 
{0: {'datetime': '10:20', 'name': 'apple', 'price': 1.0, 'qty': 5},
 1: {'datetime': '11:20', 'name': 'pear', 'price': 1.5, 'qty': 2},
 2: {'datetime': '13:20', 'name': 'banana', 'price': 5.0, 'qty': 10}}
```

Comment: You have the `pd.read_clipboard()` as part of you answer which is sketchy on it's own.  But what's more is that it's incorrect in that you miss the first half of the timestamp which is evidenced by the fact that you only show the time component in your output as a string.

Comment: That's exactly the parsing error that `read_clipboard` does., which I was referring to. However, that doesn't change any of the required behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you exactly need the output you specified one possible solution is to iterate over the dataframe by rows and construct a string by zipping columns list with row values. A crude version is:

```
def create_key_vals(iterable):
    str_list = []
    for ite in iterable:
        str_list.append(ite[0]+"="+ str(ite[1]))
    return ','.join(str_list)

new_df = df.drop('datetime', axis=1)
col_list = new_df.columns.tolist()
zipped_col_vals = [zip(col_list, row) for row in new_df.itertuples(index=False, name=False)]
col_value_list = [create_key_vals(ite) for ite in zipped_col_vals]
In [116]: col_value_list
Out[116]:
['name=apple,price=1.0,qty=5',
 'name=pear,price=1.5,qty=2',
 'name=banana,price=5.0,qty=10']
```

You can convert this into a string by:

```
In [117]: ('\n').join(col_value_list)
Out[117]: 'name=apple,price=1.0,qty=5\nname=pear,price=1.5,qty=2\nname=banana,price=5.0,qty=10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    return ss.map(lambda x:"{}={}".format(ss.name,x))
df1.loc[:,['datetime']].join(df1.iloc[:,1:].apply(function1)).apply(' '.join,axis=1).map(print)
```

out:

```
2017-11-01*10:20 name=apple qty=5 price=1.0
2017-11-01*11:20 name=pear qty=2 price=1.5
2017-11-01*13:20 name=banana qty=10 price=5.0
```