# Convert result of dataframe into Key-value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as :
[image]

I want to convert this into the form that looks like this **(E-> W.P Kinsella, Iseult Teran, Nic Rowley)(A->Jason Shinder,Bernie.....)**. And then load this format into HDFS.
Please suggest.

Comment: you can use pandas
dataframe.to_dict() in python. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185659/pandas-dataframe-to-key-value-pair

Comment: can you please remove the image and put as a text, also share what have you tried and what did not work for you ?

Comment: I'm working on scala, Is there any other way to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> 

df
.groupBy($"Age_Group")
.agg(collect_set($"Book_Author").as("Book_Author"))
.select(map($"Age_Group",$"Book_Author").as("data"))
.show(false)

+--------------------------------------------------+
|data                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|[E -> [Iseult Teran, W.P.Kinsella, W. P Kinsella]]|
|[A -> [Jason Shinder, C.S Lewis]]                 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

`Write to HDFS`

```
df
.groupBy($"Age_Group")
.agg(collect_set($"Book_Author").as("Book_Author"))
.select(map($"Age_Group",$"Book_Author").as("data"))
.write
.format("orc")
.save("<hdfs_path>")
```

**Removing Duplicates**

For example below Book_Author names are same.

- W.P.Kinsella
- W. P Kinsella

Above names almost similar below code removes duplicates & keeps only `W.P.Kinsella`

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

scala> df.show(false)
+---------+-------------+
|Age_Group|Book_Author  |
+---------+-------------+
|E        |W.P.Kinsella |
|E        |W. P Kinsella|
|E        |Iseult Teran |
|A        |C.S Lewis    |
|A        |Jason Shinder|
+---------+-------------+

scala> val windowExpr = first($"Book_Author")
                        .over(
                            Window
                            .partitionBy(lower(regexp_replace($"Book_Author","[ .]","")))
                            .orderBy($"Age_Group".asc)
                        )

scala> df
        .withColumn("Book_Author",windowExpr)
        .groupBy($"Age_Group")
        .agg(collect_set($"Book_Author").as("Book_Author"))
        .select(map($"Age_Group",$"Book_Author").as("data"))
        .show(false)
+-----------------------------------+
|data                               |
+-----------------------------------+
|[E -> [Iseult Teran, W.P.Kinsella]]|
|[A -> [Jason Shinder, C.S Lewis]]  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the elaborated solution :). I have a question though, Why are we writing into 'ORC' format only? Is there any other format that can support?(asking just out of curiosity) and how can I read the data of the ORC file?

Comment: for example to show you .. I have used ```orc``` & you can use any format as per your requirement.. for reading orc data .. ```spark.read.format("orc").load("path to your file")```